# is it possible to make postgresql always using index with in query

Tags: postgresql

I am using this sql to query the user subscribed channel articles:

```
SELECT id AS id, sub_source_id AS sub_source_id 
FROM article 
WHERE sub_source_id IN (
    
        select sub_source_id  as sub_source_id
        from sub_relation sr 
        where user_id =14
        and sub_status = 1
        limit 2
    

) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 50
```

Now I found when the user subscribe channel increase, the PostgreSQL will not using the `(sub_source_id,created_time)` index. For example, when the user subscribe 10 channel, the sql will using the index when query, when the user subscribe 100 channel, the sql did not using the `(sub_source_id,created_time)` index.why the sql did not choose the index by the subscribe channel? is it possible to keep the sql always using `(sub_source_id,created_time)` index? This is the explain with 2 id:

```
explain SELECT id AS id, sub_source_id AS sub_source_id 
FROM article 
WHERE sub_source_id IN (
    
        select sub_source_id  as sub_source_id
        from sub_relation sr 
        where user_id =14
        and sub_status = 1
        limit 2
    

) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 50
```

explain result:

```
Limit  (cost=6213.35..6213.48 rows=50 width=24)
  ->  Sort  (cost=6213.35..6217.57 rows=1686 width=24)
        Sort Key: article.created_time DESC
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=23.26..6157.34 rows=1686 width=24)
              ->  Unique  (cost=0.30..0.31 rows=2 width=8)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=0.30..0.30 rows=2 width=8)
                          Sort Key: sr.sub_source_id
                          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=2 width=8)
                                ->  Seq Scan on sub_relation sr  (cost=0.00..70.56 rows=524 width=8)
                                      Filter: ((user_id = 14) AND (sub_status = 1))
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on article  (cost=22.96..3070.09 rows=843 width=24)
                    Recheck Cond: (sub_source_id = sr.sub_source_id)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on article_sub_source_id_create_time_idx  (cost=0.00..22.75 rows=843 width=0)
                          Index Cond: (sub_source_id = sr.sub_source_id)
```

this is the explain with full ids:

```
Limit  (cost=75362.37..75368.21 rows=50 width=24)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=75362.37..108371.31 rows=282914 width=24)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=74362.35..74715.99 rows=141457 width=24)
              Sort Key: article.created_time DESC
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=77.11..69663.25 rows=141457 width=24)
                    Hash Cond: (article.sub_source_id = sr.sub_source_id)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on article  (cost=0.00..67808.71 rows=675971 width=24)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=70.56..70.56 rows=524 width=8)
                          ->  Seq Scan on sub_relation sr  (cost=0.00..70.56 rows=524 width=8)
                                Filter: ((user_id = 14) AND (sub_status = 1))
```

Comment: How many records in the table? Please provide the (formatted) output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) <your_query>`.

Comment: That doesn't look like the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE...` - can you clarify?